# Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am using `graalvm-native-image version #22.3.2`.

After budling my jar, when I try to execute native-image on my jar.I am getting the below Error

at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:153)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:104)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureFlowsGraphCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:83)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.getOrCreateMethodFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:65)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.typestate.DefaultAnalysisPolicy.staticRootMethodGraph(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:182)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.lambda$addRootMethod$0(PointsToAnalysis.java:320)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$2.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:507)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. This error is reported at image build time because class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is registered for linking at image build time by command line
at parsing org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:423)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2518)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:110)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3393)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3345)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3190)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:97)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:446)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.AnalysisParsedGraph.parseBytecode(AnalysisParsedGraph.java:135)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:685)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1162)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:1003)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:957)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:817)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:548)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:833)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:179)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:349)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:93)
... 13 more

Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. This error is reported at image build time because class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is registered for linking at image build time by command line
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:333)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:288)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedMethod(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:316)
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedInvoke(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:279)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1676)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1651)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5288)
at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3385)
... 38 more

Tried the below native-image command:
native-image --no-server -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces --features=com.apicasystem.bnet.nativeimage.Log4jReflectionProvider --features=org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature --initialize-at-run-time=com.apicasystem.bnet.BNetServiceStarter  -H:Exclude=org.slf4j.** --features=com.apicasystem.bnet.nativeimage.JakartaJsonReflectionProvider --features=com.apicasystem.bnet.nativeimage.JacksonReflectionDataProvider --features=com.apicasystem.bnet.nativeimage.DtoReflectionDataProvider --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime --allow-incomplete-classpath --no-fallback --enable-https --enable-http -H:IncludeResources=.*log4j2.xml$ -H:IncludeResources=.*MANIFEST.MF$ -H:IncludeResources=.*.js$ -H:IncludeResources=.*config.properties$ -H:TraceClassInitialization=true --link-at-build-time -H:+DeadlockWatchdogExitOnTimeout --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime -H:DeadlockWatchdogInterval=0 -jar BNetAgent-10.0.0.jar bnet-image